# How would I prove the following equivalence using the bi-conditional, or any other, logical identity?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

**(P ⇔ Q) ≡ ((P ⇒ Q) ∧ (¬P ⇒ ¬Q))**

Isn't the bi-conditional identity P ⇔ Q ≡ (P ⇒ Q) ∧ (Q ⇒ P)? With the last q and p not having the ¬ sign. If so, how can the identity and the sentence above be the same. Or am I misinterpreting something?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.   The biconditional identity *is* $(P\leftrightarrow Q)~\equiv~((P\to Q)\wedge(Q\to P))$.

There is also the contrapositive equivalence: $~~(Q\to P)~\equiv~(\neg P\to\neg Q)$

Combine them.